# How to find the sticker set through a sticker belongs to that sticker set?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm learning telethon. I can download a sticker from `message`.

```
async for message in client.iter_messages(group_name):
      if message.sticker:
         path = await message.download_media()
```

But I don't know how to get its entire sticker set.
The type of sticker I get from `message` is `Document`.
How can I get the `access_hash` and `id` of its sticker set so that I can use the following code.

```
stickers = await client(GetStickerSetRequest(
    stickerset=InputStickerSetID(
        id=sticker_message.id, access_hash=sticker_message.access_hash
    )
))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly identified, stickers are [`Document`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/document.html). What sets them apart from other documents is their [`DocumentAttributeSticker`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/document_attribute_sticker.html), which has a `stickerset` of type [`InputStickerSet`](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/input_sticker_set.html) and can be used in the [`GetStickerSetRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_sticker_set.html) method:

```py
from telethon import types

...

if message.sticker:
    for attr in message.sticker.attributes:
        if isinstance(attr, types.DocumentAttributeSticker):
            pack = await client(GetStickerSetRequest(attr.stickerset))
            # use pack
```